# Is it possible to delete recursively all deleted files/folders permanently?

Tags: dropbox, delete

Given a Dropbox folder which has many hidden deleted files/folder, currently I have to delete them manually sub folder by sub folder.

Is it possible to delete them all quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test your problem,

1. I created multiple sub-folders (non-empty) within a TEST folder.
2. I selected the TEST folder and then clicked DELETE from the drop down list.

ALL folders/sub-folders within disappeared. I did all this from within the web interface.

If someone else can verify this behaviour, I'd be much obliged.

**UPDATE**

1. Enable Keyboard Shortcuts from within [Account Settings](https://www.dropbox.com/account#settings)
2. Next, switch to your folder list and click SHOW DELETED FILES or just **press d**
3. Press **p** to **SELECT ALL DELETED ITEMS**
4. From the MORE dropdown, click **permanently delete**

This ought to make your task easier.

Comment: Yes, right. But you are going just a half of my way. The rest thing to do is to click on `More actions` - `Show deleted file` and then, select the `gray` items and choose `Permently delete`. Hope it's clearer to you now.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful. Would you give us the whole list of the hotkey?

Comment: Press ? to access the list of keyboard shortcuts in the folder view.

Comment: Awesome. How did you know that! It looks like a hidden feature of dropbox. I can't find it anywhere on dropbox homepage.

Comment: Well...most sites that have keyboard shortcuts will display a help list when you press "?"

Answer (score 2):

Keyboard shortcut doesn't work.
Most easy way: click sort all files by "Kind" column -> select range of all deleted files (click first, hold shift + click last in list). Then you can permanently delete them.
If you don't select continuous range of files it doesn't show the "permanently delete" option.